# Como usar multithreading com requests?

Tags: python-3.x, request, beautifulsoup

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um checker de disponibilidade de troca de nomes pra um jogo, mas ele é muito lento, lí sobre o módulo multithreading mas achei confuso de usar, não faço a mínima ideia de como impletamenta-lo no meu código, alguem pode me mostrar o caminho?

Aqui meu código

```
import faster_than_requests as requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


available_summoners = []
summonertxt = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("names.txt", 'r')]


for summoner in summonertxt:
    url = 'http://www.lolnames.gg/pt/br/'+summoner
    request = requests.get2str(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(request,"lxml")
    if 'card bg-success text-white' in request:
        print(summoner +' Disponivel!')
    else:
        print(summoner +' Não Disponivel')
```

Comment: a pagina ao acessar a url http://www.lolnames.gg/pt/br/  retorna Bad Request (400), esse txt é compos extras ou tentativa de dar resposta 200 ?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/541236/112052

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar essa tarefa você pode criar um objeto de Thread utilizando o módulo `threading`.

Para criar uma Thread, você deve passar a função a ser chamada no parâmetro `target` e depois você pode passar os argumentos dessa função no parâmtro `args` dentro de uma tupla ou lista.

Após ter criado o objeto, execute a thread com o método `start`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
def func(url):
    print("Obtendo a resposta de", url)

Thread(target = func, args = ("<sua_url>", )).start()
```

---

Agora que já sabe como criar uma Thread e executá-la, basta colocar o seu código dentro de uma função para ser executada numa Thread. Veja abaixo como seu código pode ficar:

```
from threading import Thread
import faster_than_requests as requests

def validate_summoner(url):

    request = requests.get2str(url)

    if 'card bg-success text-white' in request:
        print(summoner + ' Disponivel!')      
    else:
        print(summoner + ' Não Disponivel')  


available_summoners = []
summonertxt = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("names.txt")]

for summoner in summonertxt:
    url = 'http://www.lolnames.gg/pt/br/' + summoner
    Thread(target = validate_summoner, args = (url, )).start()
```

Comment: Continua lento, de que forma posso aumentar o numero de threads no meu código?

Comment: Talvez essa lentidão seja por culpa do servidor, então quanto a isto não dá para fazer nada se você não for o dono do servidor. E não tem como criar novas threads nesse caso, porque cada thread é responsável por uma requisição na url com um `summoner`. Logo, o número de threads criadas aí no código é o número de summoners que você possui na lista `summonertxt`.