# Distribuir valores de um range para várias threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread

Estou desenvolvendo um script que gera diversas URLs de um certo fórum mas com o parâmetro "id" dentro de um grande loop. Depois ele salva essas URLs e então envia um request para cada uma.

Mas eu gostaria de agilizar o processo usando as threads. O meu código está assim:

```
#importa os modulos necessarios
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bf
import threading
import random

paginas = {}
def task():
    #função que procura paginas, pega todas elas e coloca no dicionário     
    for x in random.randrange(99999):
        pagina = f'https://forumexemplo.com/index.php?id={x}'
        conteudo_pagina = s.get(pagina)
        soup = bf(conteudo_pagina.content, 'html.parser')
        
        #verifica se a pagina a ser analisada é de fato um tópico ou é apenas um redirecionamento.
        if 'quote' and 'link' in soup: 
            print("página com o id:{x} é uma conversa!\r\n")
            paginas[pagina] = soup
        else:
            print(f"id: {x}")


s = requests.Session()



#lista de threads
threads = []

#loop de criação de thread
for n in range(1,11):
    t = threading.Thread(target=task)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()


#loop pelas threads esperando elas terminarem
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Porém estou tendo problemas em relação ao loop. As threads estão trabalhando em um único id de cada vez, portanto eu tenho um resultado parecido com:

```
id: 1
id: 1
id: 1
id: 1
id: 1
id: 1
id: 2
id: 1
id: 1
id: 2
id: 1
id: 2
```

Tenho várias threads trabalhando em um só id e gostaria de randomizar os IDs para que fique mais dinâmico. Porém, quando eu troco o `for x in range(99999)` para `for x in random.randrange(1,99999)`, eu recebo o erro:

```
for x in random.randrange(1,99999):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender o que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) que `randrange` retorna um único número, e não faz sentido fazer um `for` em um número. Daí o erro "*'int' object is not iterable*", já que um número - ou seja, um `int`, que é o que `randrange` retorna - não é iterável (não pode ser percorrido com um `for`).

De qualquer forma, **para que precisa ser aleatório**? Simplesmente distribua os números do `range` entre as threads.

O problema é que na função `task` você está fazendo um *loop*, ou seja, todas as threads percorrem todos os valores do `range`. Mas se cada thread vai fazer uma única requisição, então na verdade a função deveria receber o id como parâmetro. Algo assim:

```py
def task(page_id):
    pagina = f'https://forumexemplo.com/index.php?id={page_id}'
    conteudo_pagina = s.get(pagina)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(conteudo_pagina.content, 'html.parser')
    # etc...
```

E aí você chamaria as threads, cada uma recebendo um id diferente para ser passado como argumento para a função `task`:

```py
threads = []
for i in range(99999):
    # passa o número como argumento para a função task
    t = threading.Thread(target=task, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Assim, a primeira thread vai chamar `task(0)`, a segunda chama `task(1)`, etc.

---

O problema é que isso vai gerar 99999 threads. Mas pelo que entendi você quer limitar a quantidade de threads, então uma alternativa é usar um [`ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool):

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

def task(page_id):
    pagina = f'https://forumexemplo.com/index.php?id={page_id}'
    conteudo_pagina = s.get(pagina)
    # retorna o id, a página e o soup
    return page_id, pagina, BeautifulSoup(conteudo_pagina.content, 'html.parser')

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import re

quote = re.compile(r'\bquote\b')
link = re.compile(r'\blink\b')
paginas = {}

# cria um pool com 10 threads
with ThreadPool(10) as pool:
    # task é chamada para todos os valores do range(99999)
    for page_id, pagina, soup in pool.imap_unordered(task, range(99999)):
        if soup.find(string=quote) and soup.find(string=link):
            print(f"página com o id:{page_id} é uma conversa")
            paginas[pagina] = soup
        else:
            print(f"id: {page_id}")
```

Ao percorrer os resultados (que são retornados por `imap_unordered`), a cada iteração os valores de `page_id`, `pagina` e `soup` são aqueles retornados por uma das chamadas de `task`.

**Assim, você separa as responsabilidades** e deixa o código mais organizado: na função `task` você só processa uma única URL (um único id, no caso). O `ThreadPool` se encarrega de distribuir os ids entre as threads. Depois, no `for`, você pega os resultados de cada thread e analisa o que fazer com cada um (quando adicionar o `soup` em `paginas`, etc).

Repare também que a condição do `if` mudou. Da forma que você fez antes ele **não** verifica se `quote` e `link` pertencem ao `soup`. Como essas não são tags, entendo que sejam textos que estejam no meio das páginas. Sendo assim, a busca deve ser feita com `find`, usando o argumento `string` e uma regex (assim ele busca trechos que contenham essas palavras - sem regex, vc teria que passar uma string que corresponde a todo o conteúdo do elemento).

Caso não seja esta a busca que você quer fazer, sugiro que veja na [documentação](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) todas as formas de se fazer buscas no documento.

---

Outra alternativa é usar um [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor):

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

def task(page_id):
    pagina = f'https://forumexemplo.com/index.php?id={page_id}'
    conteudo_pagina = s.get(pagina)
    # retorna o id, a página e o soup
    return page_id, pagina, BeautifulSoup(conteudo_pagina.content, 'html.parser')

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import re

quote = re.compile(r'\bquote\b')
link = re.compile(r'\blink\b')
paginas = {}

# cria um pool que terá no máximo 10 threads
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    results = []
    for id in range(99999):
        results.append(executor.submit(task, page_id=id))
    for result in as_completed(results):
        page_id, pagina, soup = result.result()
        if soup.find(string=quote) and soup.find(string=link):
            print(f"página com o id:{page_id} é uma conversa")
            paginas[pagina] = soup
        else:
            print(f"id: {page_id}")
```

Comment: Obrigado, abriu os meus olhos para pensar de uma forma mais simples e prática.

Comment: Por questão de curiosidade, eu randomizo os valores para que as threads não trabalhem todas em um valor só (visto que eu não tinha conhecimento sobre o Thread Pool) XD